# linux ext: exec'ing from a noexec partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, symbolic-link, ext4

I have reasons to mount a data partition with `noexec`, `nodev` which we will assume are valid :)

Now say i want a few directories to contain executables. Is this possible?

My first attempt was to hardlink in a place where there is no such exec restriction, but hardlinks for entire directories is another problem. And symlinks won't work. Is there anything else I can try to make that exception?

edit 1: strace after `sudo mount --bind /from_noexec/bin /with_exec/bin2 && /with_exec/bin2/script.sh` (permission is 0777)

```
$ strace /with_exec/bin2/script.sh
execve("/with_exec/bin2/script.sh", ["/with_exec/bin2/script.sh"], [/* 72 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
write(2, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32strace: exec: Permission denied
) = 32
getpid()                                = 2134
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

interesting, it shows 0600 file perm even though it is 0777 (same for files as 0750, still shows 0600 on strace).

Comment: Hardlinks are limited to within one file system. Do these particular directories absolutely have to reside on the file system which you are running noexec/nodev? Simply mounting something else there, possibly using bind mounts, would seem the obvious choice...

Comment: They are small directories in a larger filesystem contents

Comment: So bind mounts (or mounting something else) are not an option in your case?

Comment: Just re-tried `mount --bind` into a main filesystem tree that does not include noexec anywhere in the ancestry, double checked file permissions, and still get "Permission denied"

Comment: Okay; well, that rules that out, I guess.

Comment: if simply a script, `sh -c thefile`, but if the script tries to execute other files on the same partition you'll get permission denied also.